# Why these minified comments in JS don't break the code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, comments, minify

I have a web page, before send it to the browser, I delete multitple spaces, tabs and every new line using PHP.

```
                    $output = preg_replace('/\n/', '', $output);
                    $output = preg_replace('/( |    ){2,}/', ' ', $output);
```

Now, rewatching at the code, I noticed that in the JS code I left some `//comments`...

Viewing the source code I can see this:

```
[...]lback, args) {     //step == -1 -> loop    if (step > n) {   clearTimeout(tim[...]
```

Why this comment (`//step == -1 -> loop`) don't break the code?!

Why if I open the inspector I see the elements in "order" like there were the "new lines"?

I think it is a problem of the "new line", there should be some other characters that tells the browser the line end and start another, is it?

If yes, how can I definitely move the code to one single line and how can I handle the JS one line comments?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't/won't use a "real", syntax-aware minifier? It's almost certainly worth the effort in size reduction and bug avoidance to find a way to do so.

Comment: @PaulRoub the reason is that I don't know them, I have nerver used and I do not know precisely what they are and how they work... so I tried to do it myself... can you give me some link that more explain them? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file might be using DOS-type newlines (carriage-return + newline, `\r\n`). By replacing newline (`\n`), carriage-return (`\r`) remains in the file, which is the newline character used by Apple operating systems.

That means what you see as

```
[...]lback, args) {     //step == -1 -> loop    if (step > n) {   clearTimeout(tim[...]
```

is actually

```
[...]lback, args) {\r     //step == -1 -> loop\r    if (step > n) {\r   clear[...]
```

---

If you want to remove comments as well (would make sense for minimizing, but might break e.g. Internet Explorer conditional comments), you can replace them via

```
$output = preg_replace("/\\/\\/[^\r\n]*", "", $output); // single-line comments
$output = preg_replace("/\\/*[\s\S]*?*\\/", "", $output); // multi-line comments
```

You should do that *before* you replace newlines.

Comment: The regexps you have posted shouldn't work, anywere +1 for the \n\r explanation...